# Why does storing my regex in a variable break the comparison test? (Awk/Gawk)

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file called `regeces` containing a number of line-by-line regexes.  Here's an example:

```
The .* is .* years old
I like .* with lots of .*
```

I also have a data file very creatively called `data`:

```
The car is 3 years old
I like pizza with lots of pepperoni
I like tacos with lots of cheese
The house is 10 years old
A non-matching line
The couch is 5 years old
I like customers with lots of money
This line does not match
```

While the regexes are certainly not narrowly written, they are adequate to match all but the fifth and last lines of `data` and explain my problem.  Now, here's my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
        while ("cat regeces" | getline)
                {
                reg = "/" $0 "/||" reg
                }
    sub(/\|\|$/, "", reg)
    print reg
    }

# $0 ~ /I like .* with lots of .* /||/The .* is .* years old/ {
$0 ~ reg {
    print $0
    }
```

So, in the `BEGIN` section, it reads `regeces`, builds a single regex, and saves it to a variable.  As a troubleshooting aid it also prints it out.  In the body, it compares each line to the regex saved in the variable.  The commented line is for convenience in testing the problem.

The regex stored in `reg` is:

```
/I like .* with lots of .* /||/The .* is .* years old/
```

Now, if I run the program as written, it outputs every line; that is, it fails to exclude the fifth and last lines of `data`.  However, if I take the regex above and replace the program's comparison test with:

```
$0 ~ /I like .* with lots of .* /||/The .* is .* years old/
```

it works perfectly!  So, the regex appears to be just fine, but for some reason putting it in a variable and testing against the variable fails.  Why is that?  What would fix it?  Clearly regexes can be saved to variables, but what's the problem with this one?

Comment: Your regex doesn't match because you added `/` and `||` to it, and none of your lines contain `/` or `||`. It's as if you had written `$0 ~ "/I like .* with lots of .* /||/The .* is .* years old/"`.

Comment: Your script can be replaced by `grep -f regeces`.

Comment: You're right, of course.  Grep can do the same.  This is a significantly pared-down version of the script to illustrate the problem (and, as it happens, my ignorance...).  The full script analyzes the data files and produces various summaries and metadata.

Comment: `"cat regeces" | getline` = `getline < "regeces"`. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for how to write that loop correctly and other getline info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding literal slashes to the regex, so you require the matched text to contain slashes around it.

Slashes are used in the syntax of Awk itself around regular expressions; but these regular expressions you attempt to match are just strings. Compare:

```
awk 'BEGIN { var = "^hello$" }
    $0 ~ var
    /^hello$/' <<<$'hello\ngoodbye'
```

will print `hello` twice, because the two matches are equivalent.

Here is a significantly refactored version of your script:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { r = (NR>1 ? r "|" : "") $0; next }
    $0 ~ r' regeces data
```

This just reimplements `grep` but it should be easy to see how to modify or extend it to do more or different things.

Notice how we use a single `|` for alternation inside a single regex.

Comment: Ah yes, that's a simple enough way to avoid the more complex construct I had in mind. Thanks; updated.